# How to distribute a folder as a reference?

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, browser, xulrunner

I am making a C# app and I am using GeckoFX to embed Firefox into my app. For anyone interested, I got it here: http://geckofx.org/. The problem is, I want to deploy GeckoFX with my app and I don't know how to do it.

The line of code I use to initialize GeckoFX is this:

```
Skybound.Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("C:\\xulrunner");
```

This assumes that the xulrunner folder is at **C:\xulrunner**. So, my questions is this: how do I add the xulrunner folder as a reference in my app so it's copied relative to where my app is (or at least in a place where my app can find it)?

Answer (score 1):

You should create an installation for the project. You can add files as resource when you create the installation project and they will be included when the deployment is created.

I don't think you should keep the app at c:\XULRunner because I think you will run into permissions issues. You should keep it at "AppFolder\XULRunner" or "Program Files\XULRunner" if it is going to be used by multiple applications.

Answer (score 0):

Raj is correct, ideal process should be like this.

Another option if you want to avoid installer, that keep the files in resourse files and extract whereever you want befor using.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the `Xulrunner` folder to the project and set every contents presents in folder properties as `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to output Directory` to `Copy Always` . Hope this question may old but it will help someone who coming here because of `google` search like me.